# android Staticlayout draw text fuzzy

Tags: android, text, draw

Staticlayout to draw text,the words fuzzy ,weight uneven,unclear.

i want to draw the text that is double byte characters(like chinese ,Japanese,etc.)

who kowns how to fix this qustion. and how to set Font in StaticLayout

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
//  textPaint.setARGB(1, 0, 0, 0); 
textPaint.setFlags(TextPaint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);
textPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
textPaint.setTextSize(16.0F);
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(cityName,textPaint,w/WCOUNT-2-2,
                        Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,1.0F,0.0F,true); 

int wh = layout.getHeight();
int offerseth = rect.height()/2-wh/2;
int ww = layout.getWidth();
int offersetw = rect.width()/2-ww/2;
canvas.translate(rect.left+offersetw,rect.top+offerseth); 
layout.draw(canvas);
canvas.translate(-(rect.left+offersetw),-(rect.top+offerseth));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.

The font size used was too small. Changing the font size to `20.0F` made the text look fine.

Answer (score 4):

For your smaller font size, I see you did not do:

```
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```